# How to create a file in hdfs by combining two files in hadoop

Tags: join, hadoop, merge, hive, hdfs

I want to create a table in hive combining the columns of two tables.

So i want to create a single file in hdfs by including columns of both the files.

```
file1: a  b  c are the 3 columns 

file2: x  y  z are the 3 columns 

i want to create a file3: a  b  c  x  y  z  that has 6 columns.
```

How to do this ?

I tried many commands but it is appending the data into columns but i want all the columns in both the files to be present in a single file .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way will be to add `id` column to both tables (you need some column to do the join on) and then join tables on `id` column:

```
CREATE TABLE joined AS 
  SELECT first.id, first.a, first.b, first.c, second.x, second.y, second.z
    FROM first JOIN second ON (first.id = second.id)
```

Comment: Nigel Thanks for the query, it worked like a charm. What if i want to join 4 tables, and create a big table containing all the columns of all the 4 tables in Hive, How to do that

Comment: `...FROM first JOIN second ON (first.id = second.id) JOIN third ON (second.id = third.id) JOIN fourth ON (third.id = fourth.id) ...`. Same rules apply. http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hive/language_manual/joins.html